# Delay from serial port using Python

Tags: python, serial-port

I am trying to write a small Python script to read data from a serial port and simply display it to the screen.  It seems to be working, but there seems to be a delay to when I see data displayed on the screen.

```
import serial
import sys

SerialGF = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyAMA0', baudrate=115200, parity='N', stopbits=1, xonxoff=0, rtscts=0, timeout=0)

def main():
    # openSerial_GF()
    print SerialGF.isOpen()
    SerialGF.flush()
    SerialGF.flushInput()
    SerialGF.flushOutput()
    try:
        while True:
            readSerial_GF()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    SerialGF.close()
    print SerialGF.isOpen()

# def openSerial_GF():
#     global SerialGF = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyAMA0', baudrate=115200, parity='N', stopbits=1, xonxoff=0, rtscts=0, timeout=0)

def readSerial_GF():
    s = SerialGF.read(SerialGF.inWaiting())
    sys.stdout.write(s)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The data on serial port is a stream of dash characters, '-', until some event occurs.  What I am seeing a delay when the data is displayed to the screen.  What is odd is that 1024 characters are displayed at a time.  I have set the timeout to zero (0) so it should return straight away, but it isn't.  Does anyone have any ideas why there is a delay?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Maybe related to buffering that is turned on by default in `sys.stdout`. Can you run in unbuffered mode `python -u` to see if the problem persists? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering)'s another question which digs into the buffering aspect.

Comment: Or just do a `sys.stdout.flush()` after the `write`. The buffering is explained in the [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) docs (not the specific details on how `sys.stdout` is opened, which obviously happens before you even get control). On many systems, the "system default" is to buffer until either a newline is printed or some max line length (like 1024) is reached, which seems like exactly what you're seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost certainly a buffering issue. The short answer is, if you want output to show up immediately, do `sys.stdout.flush()` after each `sys.stdout.write(…)`.

On most platforms, by default,* the stdio streams end up line buffered. This means that anything written is buffered up until you either write a newline, or fill up the buffer inside stdio, which is usually some nice round length like 1024 bytes.

Python 2.x** mostly leaves buffering up to the C `stdio` library, so for full details, you want to look up your platform's [`fopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html#) and possibly `fwrite` implementations. The docs for [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) explain the options Python gives you for controlling the buffering, and the [command line and environment](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonunbuffered) docs explain how you can influence the way the stdio streams are opened. But really, rather than forcing everyone to run your program with `-u`, it's better to just explicitly `flush` when you want to make sure output appears.

<sub>* If you open the files in binary mode—which is what `-u` and `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` control—you get unbuffered output. If you open the files in text mode and `isatty()` is true or not available, you usually get line-buffered mode. Otherwise, you usually get "fully-buffered" mode, meaning there's a fixed-size buffer and writes happen when that buffer is filled.</sub>

<sub>** Note that this is all Python 2.x-specific; 3.x has its own file objects that work directly on top of native file descriptors/handles, instead of using C stdio.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, abarnert!!  Worked like a charm.